# UEFI Shelllib - ASSERT implies initialization of ShellLib?

Tags: c, uefi

i wanted to have handy control over the command line parameters. Therfor i want to use ShellLib.

My code looks like this:

```
...
#include <Library/ShellLib.h>
...
EFI_STATUS
EFIAPI
UefiMain (
    EFI_HANDLE        ImageHandle,
    EFI_SYSTEM_TABLE  *SystemTable
  )
{
    EFI_STATUS  Status;
    LIST_ENTRY  *ParamPkg;
    CHAR16      *ProblemParam;

    Status = ShellCommandLineParseEx (CmdLineCheckList, &ParamPkg, &ProblemParam, TRUE, FALSE);
...
}
```

I also have initialized *CmdLineCheckList*. But when i run the program, i get an

```
ASSERT: UefiShellLib.c (2242): mEfiShellInterface != (void *) 0
```

I looked up the code line and it looks like the ShellLibConstructor() was not called. But it should be from the shell itself, also i cannot find a example where something was done except the direct call of ShellCommandLineParseEx.
I also failed to start the Constructor manually because of problems with includes.

Can you please help me how i have to correctly initialize my application to run the ShellLib?

Comment: I now managed to call the Constructor manually - haven't helped. The ShellCOmmandLineParseEx checks for two variables which represents the old and new EFI shell. If i call the corresponding code snippet to check for those represents, it will return the one for the new EFI shell - i cannot see why it is failing.

Comment: While using masked profanity may effectively express your frustrations with the coding problem at hand, it is not appropriate in a public setting. (edited) The question itself is a good question, and as with all questions posted, should be posted in a concise and professional manner. Welcome to SO, and good luck with your coding.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example from ShellLib to access parameters: https://github.com/tianocore/edk2/blob/master/ShellPkg/Application/ShellCTestApp/ShellCTestApp.c:

```
INTN
EFIAPI
ShellAppMain (
  IN UINTN Argc,
  IN CHAR16 **Argv
  )
{
  UINTN  Index;
  if (Argc == 1) {
    Print (L"Argv[1] = NULL\n");
  }
  for (Index = 1; Index < Argc; Index++) {
    Print(L"Argv[%d]: \"%s\"\n", Index, Argv[Index]);
  }

  return 0;
}
```